# Menger's theorem and the max-flow min-cut theorem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I read this question [Proof for Menger's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56780/proof-for-mengers-theorem) but it's still not clear to me how one proves Menger's theorem using the max-flow min-cut theorem. Could you explain?

Comment: Note that the min $x-y$ edge cut has size (say $\mu$) $\ge$ the number of pairwise edge-independent paths from $x$ to $y$ (say $\ell$). Now, set the capacity of each edge to $1$, and note that the max flow from $x$ to $y$ is upper bounded by $\ell$. Since this flow is equal to the min $x-y$ cut capacity, and since each edge has has capacity one, this implies that the min $x-y$ cut has size at most $\ell$. Consequently, $\ell \le \mu \le \ell \implies \mu = \ell$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 could you make that into an answer?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, please? Don't you deal with vertex cuts in Menger's Theorem?